# Check list for duplicates

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, duplicates

I already checked many questions here in Stack Overflow but couldn't find something similar to my problem..

I generate 2 random numbers every time I click a button and I am trying to save those 2 numbers in a list so I can check every time I click the button for duplicates.

For example, on the first run I get '5' and '8', after x times I get again this combination '5' and '8' so I want to prevent this.

```
firstNum = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(min, max));
secondNum = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(min, max));

private void AddingMethod(float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{ 
    questionNumbersList.AddRange(new float[] { firstNumber, secondNumber });
    for (int i = 0; i < questionNumbersList.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Position " + i + " with list number: " + questionNumbersList[i]);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I can check my list for both numbers and see if I already got '5', '8' skip it and generate two new numbers.

Comment: What if you have 8 and 5 instead of 5 and 8?

Comment: No, this is a different one. Just check if 8 and 5 (in that order) already added.

Comment: You may use something like `if(myList.Any(x => x[0] == firstNumber && x[1] == secondNumber)` - leaving asside the fact that you shouldn´t compare floats using `==`.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure if I understood this one. Could you please write it in a way I can apply it to my function?

Comment: You didn´t provide where you create those numbers and where you intend to make the check. This is why it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: It's just a simple button in Unity calling the function which only has the code I used above in my question. I edited my question (I am sending the firstNumber and secondNumber from other script but I think that doesn't really matter with the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a list of floats you should use a list of pairs, e.g. by using tuples or your own class, where every element within such a pair has a `firstNumber` and a `secondNumber`:

```
var list = new List<(float firstNumber, float secondNumber)>();
var firstNumber = ...
var secondNumber = ...
if(list.Contains((firstNumber, secondNumber)))
    // alredy contained, create new pair ...
else
    list.Add((firstNumber, secondNumber));
```

The above requires C#7. Alternativly you can also manualy create a new [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=netframework-4.7.2) introduced on .NET 4.0, which however has no named properties:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<float, float>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(firstNumber, secondNumber));
```

Comment: `Tuple<T1, T2>` has a proper equality comparer implemented, therefore `list.Any((firstNumber, secondNumber))` will suffice.

Comment: Since I  am not using C#7, I tried the manualy create tuple but I get this error: "The type or namespace name 'Tuple<,>' could not be found". As I understand, I need to create that Tuple as a new internal class? Sorry if I am asking stupid questions, pretty new here.

Comment: The `Tuple`-**class** should be available on .NET 4 upwwards. This however does not apply for the named tuples, which are a laguage-feature introduced in C#7.

Comment: @Imantas tuple-equality seems to be only availalbe on C# 7.3. However we can use `Contains` for C#7 also.

Comment: @HimBromBeere so I can't use your suggestion :(

Comment: @Johny Then create your own pair- or tuple-class - shouldn´t be that difficult.

Comment: I will check and try to implement this. Thank you for your answer!